# Re-directed screenshot location via defaults file doesn't work

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I'm sure everyone knows about the standard changing default location where captured screenshots are stored.

A simple

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.screencapture location <enter path to folder>
killall SystemUIServer
```

should have sufficed but nothing happens.

My screenshots still save to desktop but the worst part is, when I read the file I've just written to, it tells me that the location that screenshots are being saved in is the folder that I've redirected to!

```
sudo defaults read com.apple.screencapture
```

gives

```
{
location = "/Users/Me/Documents/Screenshots/"'
}
```

However it continues to save them to my desktop. The folder remains empty; it's not as if it saves it to both the folder and the desktop.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `sudo` you change the default for the user you are `sudo`ing into, in this case the `root` user. Just run the commands without `sudo` and you should be fine.

You can also clear any settings for a user with:

```
defaults delete com.apple.screencapture
```

You can test and log out if the system doesn’t realize the change was made. That’s usually better than killing the system UI server.